# PHP mysqli results array

Tags: php, mysqli

Just learning PHP so please be kind.

I have a mysqli query which I need to pull specific results from.
For example; I need to pull the 1, 4, 7, 10, etc row, and then go back and pull the 2, 5, 8, 11, etc, row, and then go back and finally pull the 3, 6, 9, 12, etc row.  And I also need to reference each field separately.

What is the best way to do this?

The reason behind all of this is the way I'm having to display the results.
I know I can do this in ASP by moving the pointer, but I have no idea about PHP.

FYI PHP version 5.3.6.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you attempted in PHP? Any code?

Comment: Where's your attempt?

Comment: 1 query then sorting the data in php would be more efficient

Comment: I have the following working, but it just returns the query in order.  So I know the query works, it's just the order I need to fix.
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql_str);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['I_ID']
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [mysqli_fetch_all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) method on the result of your query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db_handle, "SELECT...");
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result);
```

OR, if you don't have [mysqlnd](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php), you can do this:

```
for ($rows = array(); $tmp = mysqli_fetch_array($result);) 
    $rows[] = $tmp;
```

`$rows` will contain all of the rows, so you can access each row by whatever index you want.

So if you want the 1, 4, 7, 10th row, you can do this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i += 3) {
    $rows[$i]["fieldname"]; // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need!  But for some reason it's not liking the "mysqli_fetch_all".  When it hits that the script stops.  If I comment it out, then the for loop works (tested using a simple "echo $i") but put the mysqli_fetch_all back in, and it doesn't even get to the for loop.

Comment: `echo "<P>" . $result->num_rows . "</P>"; //returns 10
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result);  // If left in stops script  
for ($f = 0; $f <= ($row_cnt-1); $f++) {  
    echo "<P>" . $f . "</P>";  // Returns 0 1 2 3 4 5 6... only if mysqli_fetch_all is commented out.  
}`

Comment: Maybe you don'thave mysqlnd.  I added an alternative way to get all rows.  Does it work now?

Comment: Yep, that other way was it!  Good to know I don't have mysqlnd.  And thank you for your help.